# Inserting into table: either invalid datatype or duplicate column name error. (But the datatype is valid and there's no duplicate)

Tags: oracle, insert

Spoiler: solution to this is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273483/oracle-inserting-into-table-error-either-duplicate-column-name-or-invalid-dat/273538#273538). the solution was really simple.

I'm trying to insert data from an external table.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
      (construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term,
      cpp,
      mutations,
      mw_kda)
SELECT *
    FROM EXTERNAL ((
      construct_id NUMBER(10),
      n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      mw_kda NUMBER (7,3))
  
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
    
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
    );
```

But now i get this error:

```
Error at Command Line : 171 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
```

Line 171 is the last line of this part

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
      (construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term,
      cpp,
      mutations,
      mw_kda)
```

Which is clearly not a duplicate column.

If I do:

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
    (construct_id, 
    n_term, 
    enz_name, 
    c_term, 
    cpp, 
    mutations, 
    mw_kda)
SELECT *
    FROM EXTERNAL ((
      ext.construct_id NUMBER (10),
      ext.n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.mw_kda NUMBER (7,3))
  
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
    
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
    );
```

I get

```
Error at Command Line : 174 Column : 10
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Line 171 is `ext.construct_id NUMBER (10),`

---

Background:

The reason I'm listing the columns out instead of just saying `insert into construct select`  is because I have a virtual column in the construct table taht's defined like this: `construct VARCHAR2 (200) GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (n_term || '-' || enz_name || '-' ||c_term || ' ' ||mutations) VIRTUAL,`
And there's no corresponding column in the csv file for it.

The second column in the ERD called CONSTRUCT is defined like this:
[image]

Edit: originally, I defined datatypes for columns from the table that I was inserting into. This was a mistake and I deleted that code, replacing it with the new version for readability. It was taking up a lot of room in this post.

(Edit: originally, I defined datatypes for columns from the table that I was inserting into. This was a mistake and I deleted that code, replacing it with the new version for readability. It was taking up a lot of room in this post.)

Answer (score 3):

If you used an IDE to develop your code, the IDE should show you exactly where you have an error.

SQL Developer shows that you have a syntax error. (magenta squiggly underline)

[image: Screenshot of SQLDeveloper showing magenta squiggly underline where there is a syntax error]

Remove the data type definitions from your first list of columns.  (The data types are defined at the time of `CREATE TABLE`)

If you ever have a question about the syntax of something, always refer to [the fine manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423).  In your case, the "data type" (in your first list of columns) is not part of the formal syntax.  Therefore - you get an error.

Image from Documentation

[image: Oracle syntax for insert_into_claues]

Comment: Thank you so much. Weird, i'm using SQL developer too and I definitely didn't have "NUMBER" highlighted with a squiggly line. That would have made it easier. But now when delete the data types, and leave everything else the same, I get an error on the line that first mentions the "mw_kda" column. SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name. I've added to my post to show what i mean.