# Oracle: Inserting into table error - either duplicate column name or invalid datatype

Tags: oracle, insert, datatypes, oracle-19c

I'm trying to insert data from an external table.

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
      (construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term,
      cpp,
      mutations,
      mw_kda)
SELECT *
    FROM EXTERNAL ((
      construct_id NUMBER(10),
      n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      mw_kda NUMBER (7,3))
  
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
    
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
    );
```

But now i get this error:

```
Error at Command Line : 171 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
```

Line 171 is the last line of this part

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
      (construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term,
      cpp,
      mutations,
      mw_kda)
```

Which is clearly not a duplicate column.

If I do:

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
    (construct_id, 
    n_term, 
    enz_name, 
    c_term, 
    cpp, 
    mutations, 
    mw_kda)
SELECT *
    FROM EXTERNAL ((
      ext.construct_id NUMBER (10),
      ext.n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      ext.mw_kda NUMBER (7,3))
  
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
    
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
    );
```

I get

```
Error at Command Line : 174 Column : 10
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Line 171 is `ext.construct_id NUMBER (10),`

Comment: Please don't put an answer in the question. If you feel a separate answer is needed beyond the one you accepted, by all means self-answer in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External table name is `construct_ext`

```
CREATE TABLE construct_ext
  (    construct_id NUMBER (10),
      n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      mw_kda NUMBER (7,3)
  )
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
   
    ACCESS PARAMETERS 
  (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET US7ASCII 
        TERRITORY AMERICA
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
        LOGFILE bad_files:'logflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.log'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
   ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
    

INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct ( construct_id ) ) */
INTO construct 
    (construct_id, 
    n_term, 
    enz_name, 
    c_term, 
    cpp, 
    mutations, 
    mw_kda)
SELECT 
      construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term ,
      cpp ,
      mutations ,
      mw_kda
FROM
      construct_ext ext
  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
);
```

**Edit:-After creating external table verify if you're able to query the table**

Edit:- As per @a_horse_with_no_name you can access external table without creating using [inline external table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/inline-external-tables-18c) for Database version 18c and above

The problem arises when you try to insert target table without creating external table(hope someone can shed light on this) work around is to create staging table then insert into target table

```
    CREATE TABLE construct_stg  
    AS
    -- select part works without creating external table 
    SELECT *
        FROM EXTERNAL (
        (
          construct_id NUMBER(10),
          n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
          enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
          c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
          cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
          mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
          mw_kda NUMBER (7,3)
          )
        TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
        DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_import 
        ACCESS PARAMETERS (
            RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
            TERRITORY AMERICA
            SKIP 1
            BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.bad'
            --LOGFILE bad_files:'logflie_insert_into_construct_from_construct.log'--create different directory for log file or skip this line 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
            (
              construct_id,
              n_term ,
              enz_name,
              c_term ,
              cpp ,
              mutations ,
              mw_kda 
              )
            )
    
        LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
        REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED)ext_tab;
 
   CREATE INDEX idx_construct_id ON construct_stg(construct_id);
 
   ALTER TABLE construct_stg ADD CONSTRAINT pk_construct_id_stg PRIMARY KEY (construct_id) USING INDEX;  -- to enforce unique or skip this



    INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( consruct,idx_construct_id) */
    INTO construct 
    (construct_id, 
    n_term, 
    enz_name, 
    c_term, 
    cpp, 
    mutations, 
    mw_kda)
SELECT 
      construct_id,
      n_term ,
      enz_name,
      c_term ,
      cpp ,
      mutations ,
      mw_kda
FROM
      construct_stg ext
  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c
        WHERE c.n_term = ext.n_term
        AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
        AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
        AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
        AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
);
```